# Yii авторизация

Tags: yii, auth

Добрый день.

У меня проблема с авторизацией в Yii.

При авторизации я складываю переменную в сессию. А походу авторизация идет по кукисам и при длительном времени переменная в сесси, теряется. setState не хочу записывать, так как эта переменная хранится в куках...

Описал сумбурно, но в целом проблема думаю описана.

Помогите решить - посоветуйте решение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не совсем понял вопроса. Юзер проходит авторизацию - в сессию вы записываете состояние данного подключения (авторизирован, неавторизирован) А само значение сесси передаются через куки - правильно?
смотрим код CwebUser

```
public function setState($key,$value,$defaultValue=null)
    {
        $key=$this->getStateKeyPrefix().$key;
        if($value===$defaultValue)
            unset($_SESSION[$key]);
        else
            $_SESSION[$key]=$value;
    }
```

значить сохраняет не в куки а в сессию, но как уже сказали вам в ответе сессия тоже имеет время жизни. Просто у вас возможно время хранения куки больше время жизни сессии.
Поэтому при заходе насайт происходит следующее - клас получает куки, оттуда берет сессию - но сессия то уже нет - поэтому узер неавторизируется

Comment: При успешной авторизации я записываю в текущую сессию дополнительные параметры. А yii авторизуется не на основе PHPSESSID с подключением нужной сесси, а вроде бы берет свою переменную, где непосредственно хранит идентификатор юзера. Поэтому через время сессия может тупо умереть а вот пользователь так и останется авторизованным. В этом случае параметры сохраненные в сессии теряются. Все уе перечитал, никак не могу найти нормальной альтернативы авторизации в yii

Comment: Хмм. Полезна информация. И почему я сразу не додумался посмотреть в этот класс!Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

У сессии есть такое понятие как время_жизни, в куках должен хранится только идентификатор сесси, а сама сессия хранится на сервере в виде файлов либо же в БД, в зависимости от выбранного адаптера для хранилища сессий.